# How can I join a list in python after an 'n' number of commas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I take a large list like this:

```
line = ['8', '2', '22', '97', '38', '15', '0', '40', '0', '75', '4', '5', '7', '78', '52', '12', '50', '77', '91', '8', '49', '49', '99', '40', '17', '81', '18', '57', '60', '87', '17', '40', '98', '43', '69', '48', '4', '56', '62', '0', '81', '49', '31', '73', '55', '79', '14', '29', '93', '71', '40', '67', '53', '88', '30', '3', '49', '13', '36', '65', '52', '70', '95', '23', '4', '60', '11', '42', '69', '24', '68', '56', '1', '32', '56', '71', '37', '2', '36', '91', '22', '31', '16', '71', '51', '67', '63', '89', '41', '92', '36', '54', '22', '40', '40', '28', '66', '33', '13', '80', '24', '47', '32', '60', '99', '3', '45', '2', '44', '75', '33', '53', '78', '36', '84', '20', '35', '17', '12', '50', '32', '98', '81', '28', '64', '23', '67', '10', '26', '38', '40', '67', '59', '54', '70', '66', '18', '38', '64', '70', '67', '26', '20', '68', '2', '62', '12', '20', '95', '63', '94', '39', '63', '8', '40', '91', '66', '49', '94', '21', '24', '55', '58', '5', '66', '73', '99', '26', '97', '17', '78', '78', '96', '83', '14', '88', '34', '89', '63', '72', '21', '36', '23', '9', '75', '0', '76', '44', '20', '45', '35', '14', '0', '61', '33', '97', '34', '31', '33', '95', '78', '17', '53', '28', '22', '75', '31', '67', '15', '94', '3', '80', '4', '62', '16', '14', '9', '53', '56', '92', '16', '39', '5', '42', '96', '35', '31', '47', '55', '58', '88', '24', '0', '17', '54', '24', '36', '29', '85', '57', '86', '56', '0', '48', '35', '71', '89', '7', '5', '44', '44', '37', '44', '60', '21', '58', '51', '54', '17', '58', '19', '80', '81', '68', '5', '94', '47', '69', '28', '73', '92', '13', '86', '52', '17', '77', '4', '89', '55', '40', '4', '52', '8', '83', '97', '35', '99', '16', '7', '97', '57', '32', '16', '26', '26', '79', '33', '27', '98', '66', '88', '36', '68', '87', '57', '62', '20', '72', '3', '46', '33', '67', '46', '55', '12', '32', '63', '93', '53', '69', '4', '42', '16', '73', '38', '25', '39', '11', '24', '94', '72', '18', '8', '46', '29', '32', '40', '62', '76', '36', '20', '69', '36', '41', '72', '30', '23', '88', '34', '62', '99', '69', '82', '67', '59', '85', '74', '4', '36', '16', '20', '73', '35', '29', '78', '31', '90', '1', '74', '31', '49', '71', '48', '86', '81', '16', '23', '57', '5', '54', '1', '70', '54', '71', '83', '51', '54', '69', '16', '92', '33', '48', '61', '43', '52', '1', '89', '19', '67', '48']
```

and make it to where after every twentieth number it joins it with a semi colon and space, ('; ') and every other time it just joins it with a space?

It would look something like this except larger:

"8 22 2 97; 58 33 44 82; 86..." and so on.

Comment: your question is nice. You were lucky not to stumble on "where iz your keude" police :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

easy with a list comprehension and 2 nested `str.join`:

```
"; ".join([" ".join(line[i:i+20]) for i in range(0,len(line),20)])
```

You slice the list to take every 20 elements for the inner part, to create the list of space separated strings, and join the resulting list with your "outer" separator.

It works even if the list size isn't dividable by 20 and is super fast

(note that I'm forcing list creation for the outside `join` because `join` needs to create a list anyway. It's faster than passing a generator comprehension in that case)

Comment: Beat me to it... Nice note about forcing the list creation, didn't know join did that. Good to know!

Comment: and your answer is still correct and pythonic. Creating a function passing `n` is a nice touch.

Comment: Thanks! I understand most of the solution but Im not sure I get whats going on here: range(0, len(line) ,20)? Could you explain this.

Comment: Ok so its a step by 20 got it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
def joinit(line, n): 
    return ': '.join(' '.join(line[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(line), n))
```

Join a section of length `n`: `' '.join(line[i:i+n])`,
Doing this for all the sections, and join the resulting list with the second delimiter, `': '`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple iteration approach:

```
counter = 0
result = ""
for num in line:
   counter += 1
   result += str(num)
   if counter == 20:
       result += ";"
       counter = 0
   result += " "
```

Basically we go through each element of the list, joining it to the `result` string. Using the `counter` var, we can add a semicolon every 20 iterations by checking if it's value is 20 each time around. Once it reaches 20, we add the semicolon and reset its value to 0.

Comment: that has still very poor performance because it spends its time concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using an enumeration of your line `list`, you can use the index to specify when it should be a `;` on multiples of 20...

```
joined = ''
for i, num in enumerate(line):
    joined += str(num)
    joined += ' ' if (i + 1) % 20 != 0 else '; '
```

Comment: although that works, it has still very poor performance because it spends its time concatenating strings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is that not what the `join` function does under the hood?

Comment: no, the `join` function knows the size of the string, so it preallocates the right size directly instead of constantly reallocating/increasing string size. What is not that bad with lists is bad with strings. That's one of the reasons why you cannot do `sum()` on strings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah, I see. That actually makes sense. Never considered that

Comment: I used that concatenation approach once on a big list of lines and it crawled so much that I had to google that... it's quadratic time because of all the copies.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Right. Thinking about what the implementation in C would be, I'm now realizing how big of a nightmare that really is computationally!

Comment: Yes. And the `+=` doesn't help much because python needs to keep the reference of the previous string (string immutability) so it cannot perform in-place add. I heard there are some implementations where it can do it if noone else references it, though. But I wouldn't count on it. In C you could perform in-place, because you don't care about immutability in that case.

Answer (score 0):

method 1

modulus gives you the division remainder; so create a blank string, add every item in list and seperate by space or semicolon depending on item number:

```
new_string = ''
z= len(line)
for i in range(z):
    new_string += (line[i])
    if (i%20==0) and (z>i>0):
        new_string += '; '
    else:
        new_string += ' '
print new_string
```

method 2

first add semicolon to every 20th item in list; then convert to string and remove commas and quotes:

```
for i in range(1,(len(line)-1)):
    if i%20==0: line[i]+=';'
line  = (((str(line)[:-1:])[1:]).replace("'",'')).replace(",",'')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = ''

for a in line: string+= a+'?' if (line.index(a)+1) % 20 else a+'!'

print(string)
```

simple as this!

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
length = 20
result = '; '.join((' '.join(line[idx: idx + length]) for idx in range(len(line) - n)))
```

Comment: not the downvoter, but your code 1) isn't explained and 2) doesn't work because elements are repeated